# Hosts file on OpenWRT router blocks cmd connections, but Chrome still connects

Tags: networking, google-chrome, router, dns, hosts-file

I have OpenWRT installed on a TP-Link Archer C7 router, and have added `0.0.0.0 domain.com` to `/etc/hosts`. This seems to have the desired effect when `ping`-ing, `nslookup`-ing or `curl`-ing that domain on a Windows 10 command line, as shown here:

```
C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop>ping domain.com -n 1
Ping request could not find host domain.com. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop>nslookup domain.com 192.168.1.1
Server:  OpenWrt.lan
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    domain.com
Address:  0.0.0.0


C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop>curl domain.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: domain.com
```

But accessing the website through Chrome still works...why???

I have tried clearing the DNS cache with `ipconfig /flushdns`, rebooting my router and rebooting my PC, but to no avail. I even tried loading the site on Edge (*shudders*), which was hard for me to even type let alone use to actually load a website, but guess what??? No problems whatsoever loading that damned website!

The final goal of this whole operation is to setup a LAN-global ad blocklist, since I'm sick of managing different software across 5 different OSes. But I can't even get a simple test to reliably work!

MTIA for any clues as to what gremlins are lurking in my computer/LAN ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OMG I feel like such an idiot! The problem was simply that the site I was testing with must use .htaccess rules or the like to enforce inclusion of the www prefix! And in my hosts file, I obviously wasn't checking for that!

The Chrome developers could have made this blunder a little easier to spot by not hiding the www until focusing on the omnibar and pressing left arrow, but still, it was mostly my own stupidity that caused this issue.